# System of equations returns a warning, and I cannot figure why

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a simple set of equations on Overleaf, with this code:

```
\[ \left \{ \begin{tabular}{l}  
$w_{ji} \leftarrow w_{li}$ \\ 
$w_{li} \leftarrow w_{ji}$ \\
$w_{lk} \leftarrow w_{jk}$ \\
$w_{jk} \leftarrow w_{lk}$
\right. \end{tabular} \]
```

At this point the code even looks right in the render, but Overleaf still claims that something is wrong with it, and pats itself on the shoulder, returning this warning for the last of these 6 rows:

```
Missing $ inserted.
```

I'd love to know what is wrong with this code, even if not to proliferate warnings. Thanks!

UPDATE: And also, actually, another question that I was wondering about, but forgot to ask: why do I need to have all those `$` in every row. And by "need" I mean that with them the equation looks all right, but if I remove them, the equation gets messed up, and Overleaf generates warnings, claiming that it added some extra `$`s there for me.

Comment: `\right. \end{tabular} ` should be `\end{tabular} \right. `

Comment: but this should not be a `tabular` if you used `array` all the entries would be math mode without needing `$` everywhere

Comment: Omg, right, I closed it incorrectly. When I swap them, the warning disappears. HOWEVER I still seem to need $s in every row, which is really annoying, as from my understanding of how \[ works I should not need them! Yet if I try to remove them, Overleaf gives me a warning for each and every row, and claims that $ was missing, but it added it. Also the rendered formula gets broken: while the second "w" in each row is still shown in math model, the first one is shown in straight bold font.

Comment: as I say that is because you used `tabular` which is not designed for math, use `array` (which is identical to `tabular` but for math)

Comment: please don't edit solutions into the question, it messes up the long term question.answer format of the site

Comment: Sorry, and thank you. I just realized that I actually had 2 questions, but asked only one. But you are right; I shouldn't mix questions with answers, so I edited it again. Hopefully it's OK now. Two questions, two answers.

Comment: And switching to `array` worked, thank you! Yay!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tabular`, but `\right.` should go outside it.

You don't need all those `$` symbols if you use `array`. However, there's a slicker way that also gives a much better output. See what happens in the three cases: the first two produce the same output, but the first is much easier to type; in the third case the output is more cramped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array} % for the second and third solutions

\begin{document}

This uses \texttt{alignedat}
\[
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&w_{ji} &&\leftarrow w_{li} \\
&w_{li} &&\leftarrow w_{ji} \\
&w_{lk} &&\leftarrow w_{jk} \\
&w_{jk} &&\leftarrow w_{lk}
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\]

Compare with \texttt{array}
\[
\begin{cases}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{l >{{}}l}
w_{ji} &\leftarrow w_{li} \\
w_{li} &\leftarrow w_{ji} \\
w_{lk} &\leftarrow w_{jk} \\
w_{jk} &\leftarrow w_{lk}
\end{array}
\end{cases}
\]

Compare with \texttt{array}, but no \texttt{cases}
\[
\left\{
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{l >{{}}l}
w_{ji} &\leftarrow w_{li} \\
w_{li} &\leftarrow w_{ji} \\
w_{lk} &\leftarrow w_{jk} \\
w_{jk} &\leftarrow w_{lk}
\end{array}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- order of `right.` and `end{tabular}` is wrong
- simpler is to use `array` tan tabular (see @David comments)
  you can write this set of math expression with `cases` too:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}
  with \verb+array+
  \[
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{l}
  w_{ji} \leftarrow w_{li} \\
  w_{li} \leftarrow w_{ji} \\
  w_{lk} \leftarrow w_{jk} \\
  w_{jk} \leftarrow w_{lk}
  \end{array}
  \right.
  \]
  with \verb+cases+
  \[
  \begin{cases}
  w_{ji} \leftarrow w_{li}  \\
  w_{li} \leftarrow w_{ji}  \\
  w_{lk} \leftarrow w_{jk}  \\
  w_{jk} \leftarrow w_{lk}
  \end{cases}
  \]
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Switching to `array` worked! I've seen examples with `cases`, and tried to use them, but for some reason they wouldn't work. Maybe that's because I was opening and closing math mode with `$$`? I've read since then that it's not a good approach, so now I'm changing it to `\[` everywhere...

Comment: @ampanmdagaba, `$$` is TeX switch to display math, for LaTeX is defined `\[`. however, `$$` should work in LateX too.